# How to npm install the Tableau Extensions API SDK?

Tags: tableau-api

When I try to Start a web server to host the sample dashboard extensions, on reading this page:

https://tableau.github.io/extensions-api/docs/trex_getstarted.html

I've got this error, after try to install node dependencies, with npm install:

```
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network request to https://artifactory.prod.tableautools.com/artifactory/api/npm/tab-npm/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In mosnpm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network request to https://artifactory.prod.tableautools.com/artifactory/api/npm/tab-npm/yocto-queue/-/yocto-queue-0.1.0.tgz failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config't cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
```

I suspect the repository have a problem?

Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the following items are in your directory `yarn.lock`, `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` remove them. After that run this command:

```
npm install -f
```

The `-f` or `--force` argument will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.